# how to make a composite foreign key (not composite primary key) as unique in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a table and in that table i have a primary key, and a composite foreign key(combination of 2 foreign keys).
I want to know how do I create a composite foreign key as unique which means that I don't want that composite foreign key duplicate again in the table?

this is the query for it

```
create table official_baby_toys(
official_baby_toys_id int,
baby_id int,
toy_id int,
toy_size_id,
primary key(official_baby_toys_id)
foreign key(baby_id,toy_id) references baby_toy(baby_id,toy_id),
foreign key(toy_size_id) references toy_size(toy_size_id),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create two single foreign keys, then create the UNIQUE KEY with both fields:

```
create table official_baby_toys(
official_baby_toys_id int,
baby_id int,
toy_id int,
toy_size_id,
primary key(official_baby_toys_id)
foreign key(baby_id) references baby_toy(baby_id),
foreign key(toy_id) references baby_toy(toy_id),
foreign key(toy_size_id) references toy_size(toy_size_id),
unique key(baby_id, toy_id)
)
```

Also I don't know your DB schema, but I feel like `baby_id` should actually reference to `baby(baby_id)` rather than `baby_toy(baby_id)`.

**Edit:**
You can also create a composite foreign key, but you need to create index (or a primary key, which will also create an index) for these two fields first:

```
CREATE TABLE baby_toy (
  # other field defs
  baby_id int,
  toy_id int,
  primary key(baby_id, toy_id)
  # OR index(baby_id, toy_id)
);
```

Then in the `official_baby_toys` you should be able to create composite foreign key.

Comment: Can't you create a unique key with composite foreign key? without creating two single foreign keys?

Comment: also is this a good practice? I mean having a composite foreign key in tables.

Comment: You can create a composite foreign key, but as far as I remember you need to create an index on your `baby_toy` table with `INDEX (baby_id, toy_id)`, then use `FOREIGN KEY (baby_id, toy_id) REFERENCES baby_toy(baby_id, toy_id)`, then if you want this to be unique it would be better to create unique key on `baby_toy` table.

Comment: Why do I have to create two foreign keys instead of creating a composite foreign key? What's wrong in it? you mean that would be a bad DB design?

Comment: Any what do you mean by creating an INDEX? you mentioned that I have to create an index. can you show an example of it?

Comment: I did provide an example for creating an index. You can refer to the official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html, section "Examples of Foreign Key Clauses" - the second example defines a composite foreign key. You don't need to create two foreign keys, it is just one of the ways. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate that is fine

Comment: Get rid of `primary key(official_baby_toys_id)`; instead, have `primary key(baby_id, toy_id)`.